# How to close mobile menu panel when clicking on my custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to join both function but I still without correct result after many tests.

Here it's the sample code I use =>

```
function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var isMenuOpen = false;

$('.menu_btn').click(function()
{
    if (isMenuOpen == false)
    {
        $("#menu_smartphone").clearQueue().animate({
            left : '0px' 
        })            
  $("#grey_back").fadeIn('fast');
        $(".close").fadeIn(300);

        isMenuOpen = true;
    } 
});     
$('#grey_back').click(function()
{
    if (isMenuOpen == true)
    {
        $("#menu_smartphone").clearQueue().animate({
            left : '-200px'
        })
        $("#page").clearQueue().animate({
            "margin-left" : '0px'
        })            
  $("#grey_back").fadeOut('fast');
        $(this).fadeOut(200);

        isMenuOpen = false;
    }
});
});
```

So what I wish, is when clicking into .menu_btn the side panel open (the fonction is ok), but when reclicking on it (when isMenuOpen = true), it close the side panel.
With this code, the side panel close only when clicking into the #grey_back

Here it's a demo =>
https://jsfiddle.net/vsfogccy/

Comment: Provide jsfiddle or code snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vsfogccy/

Comment: You might take a more simple approach and using an add/remove class. http://jsfiddle.net/ex8ddv5q/1/

Comment: Probably, but I want to use both function to close the side panel, by clicking into the div, both by clicking the grey_back div
In your demo that's work only when clicking into the menu_btn div :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to simplify your code and optimize the animations. `transform: translate()` works much smoother then animating static position, as in your case - `left` property.

```js
var isGreyInvisible = true;
$('.menumobile').click(function() {
  if (isGreyInvisible) {
    $('#grey_back').fadeIn();
    isGreyInvisible = false;
  } else {
    $('#grey_back').fadeOut();
    isGreyInvisible = true;
  }
  $('#menu_smartphone').toggleClass('open');
  $('.bar1').toggleClass('change1');
  $('.bar2').toggleClass('change2');
  $('.bar3').toggleClass('change3');
});

$('#grey_back').click(function() {
  $('#menu_smartphone').removeClass('open');
  $('#grey_back').fadeOut();
  isGreyInvisible = true;
  $('.bar1').removeClass('change1');
  $('.bar2').removeClass('change2');
  $('.bar3').removeClass('change3');
});
```

```css
/* Menu mobile */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#menu_smartphone {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  color: webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e6e6e6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 25%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 25%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 25%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 25%);
}
#menu_smartphone ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #999999;
}
#menu_smartphone ul li {
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#menu_smartphone ul li:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
#menu_smartphone ul li a {
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#grey_back {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
/* Menu animé en css */

.menumobile {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */

.change1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
/* Fade out the second bar */

.change2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Rotate last bar */

.change3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
.open {
  transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menumobile menu_btn">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
<div id="grey_back">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="menu_smartphone" class="menu_mobile_app closed" align="left">
  <ul style="overflow-y:auto;">
    <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: That's look like really more simple and work, but how I can join my "grey_back" overlay and the close function when clicking on it like when clicking on my "menu_btn" ?

Comment: @WolwxAliasXavierRedondo Unfortunately I don't get your point, everything which you have mentioned in your problem, works now.

Comment: Do you checked my jsfiddle ? In my demo you can see the grey_back overlay, and by clicking on it the side menu panel is closed. In your demo that's not present.

Comment: @WolwxAliasXavierRedondo It's fine now? Would be cool if you would upvote&mark the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect now :D